# Creating 10K connections and sending data

Tags: mqtt, paho, thingsboard

im doing some testing using Thingsboard (Open source IoT platform), basically, Im trying to see the performance of it, and also the performance of the cassandra database and postgresql database, when receiving data from multiple devices.

Currently, Im sending the data over paho-mqtt, and before it, I created the devices correctly. I am able to send data every 10 seconds for 200 devices, for a long period of time. However, my goal is to scale it and see the performance when receiving data from 10K devices. But, if I want to test (using 1000 devices), im not able to connect to them at all. Is there any limitation to the amount of devices/clients paho-mqtt can create using threads?

I have read that it might be related to the amount of open file descriptors, and when I see my limit (with ulimit -a), I see that my limit is 1024. However, I am able to ask for more cpu's, and when I use 4 cpus, my limit is 4096. However, when I try to run my script, most of the time, only one or two clients connect and the rest (998 clients) are disconnected.

I am doing something wrong with my code?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import threading
import logging
import thingsboard_objects as Things
import random
import datetime
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


init_time = time.time()


def Connect(client, broker, port, token, keepalive, run_forever=False):
    connflag = False
    delay = 5
    print("connecting ",client)
    badcount = 0  # counter for bad connection attempts
    while not connflag:
        print(logging.info("connecting to broker " + str(broker)))
        # print("connecting to broker "+str(broker)+":"+str(port))
        print("Attempts ", str(badcount))
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            client.username_pw_set(token)
            client.connect(broker, port, keepalive)
            connflag = True

        except:
            client.badconnection_flag = True
            logging.info("connection failed " + str(badcount))
            badcount += 1
            if badcount >= 3 and not run_forever:
                return -1
                raise SystemExit  # give up

    return 0


def wait_for(client, msgType, period=2, wait_time=20, running_loop=False):
    """Will wait for a particular event gives up after period*wait_time, Default=10
seconds.Returns True if succesful False if fails"""
    # running loop is true when using loop_start or loop_forever
    client.running_loop = running_loop  #
    wcount = 0
    while True:
        logging.info("waiting" + msgType)
        if msgType == "CONNACK":
            if client.on_connect:
                if client.connected_flag:
                    return True
                if client.bad_connection_flag:  #
                    return False

        if msgType == "SUBACK":
            if client.on_subscribe:
                if client.suback_flag:
                    return True
        if msgType == "MESSAGE":
            if client.on_message:
                if client.message_received_flag:
                    return True
        if msgType == "PUBACK":
            if client.on_publish:
                if client.puback_flag:
                    return True

        if not client.running_loop:
            client.loop(.01)  # check for messages manually
        time.sleep(period)
        wcount += 1
        if wcount > wait_time:
            print("return from wait loop taken too long")
            return False
    return True


def client_loop(client, broker, port, token, keepalive=600, loop_function=None,
                loop_delay=10, run_forever=False):
    """runs a loop that will auto reconnect and subscribe to topics
    pass topics as a list of tuples. You can pass a function to be
    called at set intervals determined by the loop_delay
    """
    client.run_flag = True
    client.broker = broker
    print("running loop ")
    client.reconnect_delay_set(min_delay=1, max_delay=12)

    while client.run_flag:  # loop forever

        if client.bad_connection_flag:
            break
        if not client.connected_flag:
            print("Connecting to " + broker)
            if Connect(client, broker, port, token, keepalive, run_forever) != -1:
                if not wait_for(client, "CONNACK"):
                    client.run_flag = False  # break no connack
            else:  # connect fails
                client.run_flag = False  # break
                print("quitting loop for  broker ", broker)

        client.loop(0.01)

        if client.connected_flag and loop_function:  # function to call
            loop_function(client, loop_delay)  # call function

    time.sleep(1)
    print("disconnecting from", broker)
    if client.connected_flag:
        client.disconnect()
        client.connected_flag = False


def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print(buf)


#def on_message(client, userdata, message):
#    time.sleep(1)
#    print("message received", str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        client.connected_flag = True  # set flag
        for c in clients:
            if client == c["client"]:
                if c["sub_topic"] != "":
                    client.subscribe(c["sub_topic"])

                    print("connected OK")
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=", rc)
        client.loop_stop()


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    client.connected_flag = False  # set flag
    # print("client disconnected ok")


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("In on_pub callback mid= ", mid)


def pub(client, loop_delay):

    rmd_current = round(random.uniform(0.6, 50.0), 2)
    rmd_pressure = round(random.uniform(0.6, 50.0), 2)
    global init_time
    if time.time() - init_time >= 3600:
        rmd_mnc = round(random.uniform(5.0, 30.0), 2)
        rmd_sdc = round(random.random(), 2)
        rmd_mnp = round(random.uniform(5.0, 30.0), 2)
        rmd_sdp = round(random.random(), 2)

        client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry',
                       '{"Current": "%s","Pressure": "%s","Str": "12341","Stp": "12340","AL1": "~","AL2": "~",'
                       '"AL3": "~","AL4": "~","AL5": "~","AL6": "~","AL7": "~","AL8": "~"}' % (rmd_current, rmd_pressure))
        client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry',
                       '{"MnC": "%s", "SdC": "%s", "Str": "2554","Stp": "2554", '
                       '"MnP": "%s", "SdP": "%s"}' % (rmd_mnc, rmd_sdc, rmd_mnp, rmd_sdp))

        init_time = time.time()
    else:
        client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry',
                       '{"Current": "%s","Pressure": "%s","Str": "12341","Stp": "12340","AL1": "~","AL2": "~",'
                       '"AL3": "~","AL4": "~","AL5": "~","AL6": "~","AL7": "~","AL8": "~"}' % (rmd_current, rmd_pressure))
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(loop_delay)
    pass


def Create_connections():
    for i in range(n_clients):
        cname = "client" + str(i)
        t = int(time.time())
        client_id = cname + str(t)  # create unique client_id
        client = mqtt.Client(client_id)  # create new instance
        clients[i]["client"] = client
        clients[i]["client_id"] = client_id
        clients[i]["cname"] = cname
        broker = clients[i]["broker"]
        port = clients[i]["port"]
        token = clients[i]["token"]
        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
        client.on_publish = on_publish
        #client.on_message = on_message
        t = threading.Thread(target=client_loop, args=(client, broker, port, token, 600, pub))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #things_location = input("What type of thingsboard installation are you working with (demo/local)? ")
    things_location = "local"
    if things_location == "local":
        type_install = 'cseetprj03.essex.ac.uk:8080'
        broker = 'cseetprj03.essex.ac.uk'
    else:
        type_install = broker = 'demo.thingsboard.io'

    header = Things.get_credentials(things_location)
    my_devices = Things.get_devices_id(header, type_install)

    clients = []
    for device in my_devices:
        device_info = {"broker": broker, "port": 1883, "name": device["name"],
                       "token": Things.get_device_token(device["id"]["id"], header, type_install)}
        clients.append(device_info)

    n_clients = len(clients)
    mqtt.Client.connected_flag = False  # create flag in class
    mqtt.Client.bad_connection_flag = False  # create flag in class

    threads = []
    print("Creating Connections ")
    no_threads = threading.active_count()
    print("current threads =", no_threads)
    print("Publishing ")
    Create_connections()

    print("All clients connected ")
    no_threads = threading.active_count()
    print("current threads =", no_threads)
    print("starting main loop")
    try:
        while no_threads == 1001:
            time.sleep(10)
            no_threads = threading.active_count()
            print("current threads =", no_threads)
            for c in clients:
                if not c["client"].connected_flag:
                    print("broker ", c["broker"], " is disconnected")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("ending")
        for c in clients:
            c["client"].run_flag = False
    time.sleep(10)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For starters, from code-review

```
t = int(time.time())
```

will return the same value for many iterations through the loop, causing the
client id to be the same. Multiple clients with the same client id will disconnect
each other.

When you solve that one, you will find that Python is not multi-processor multi-
threading, unless you use the process-based multiprocessing package. Likely your
performance will not be good enough to maintain the 10k threads.

BTW, why re-invent the wheel of an MQTT simulator? Disclaimer: we sell such a
product, and 10k connections is trivial.

Comment: Beside the client id error. What do you recommend to do? Are you saying to use multiprocessing library instead of threading? I have a reasonable amount of resources, so maybe I can try it. Where can I find a mqtt simulator? I dont understand your last paragraph of your reply

Comment: trivial means that it is something easy? Im doing a research project, so I dont know if a paid solution might be something affordable for a student

Comment: Google is your friend.